# IIS Virtual Directory maximum number of connections to Windows share

Tags: windows, iis, file-sharing

**Disclaimer. I'm a developer, largely ignorant on what actually happens with virtual directories and such.

A recent outage was explained away as too many connections to a Windows file share, and it didn't seem like a good enough answer to me, so I wanted to ask the experts here.

Say I have 30 machines running IIS, 8 & 8.5 mixed. All of them are running five sites. Each site has three virtual directories, \vdir1, \vdir2 and \vdir3 that point to `\\fileserver\data\dir1`, `\\fileserver\data\dir2` and `\\fileserver\data\dir3` respectively. Physical Path Credentials are all set to the same user and Physical Path Credentials Logon is set to ClearText.

1. If my application doesn't make use of these virtual directories, meaning we never call Server.MapPath() to them anymore because we're using Azure BLOB storage now, and there is no traffic to the virtual dirs externally, does IIS itself maintain any active connections to the shared folders? If so how many?
2. How many connections can a Windows file share handle at once? Even if IIS does have one connection per virtual directory, it doesn't seem likely to me that 30 x 5 x 3 = 450 connections would overwhelm a file share.

Also, is there anywhere you could point me on the web that documents at a lowish level what's going on in IIS with virtual directories or Windows file sharing in general and any other specifics related to number of connections allowed? [This](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) isn't super detailed.

Comment: I'm very dubious of the explanation "too many connections to a Windows file share".

Comment: I agree, Evan. That's why I'd like to see if I can find a more specific answer here.

Comment: Having similar problem. Did you ever get more details?

Comment: Sadly, no more details.